# Better way of running a series of commands simultaneously in UNIX/Linux Shell?

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash, shell, unix

I want to know the good practice of performing a series of commands simultaneously in UNIX/Linux. Suppose that I have a program, program_a, which requires one parameter. I have stored parameters line by line in a file. So I wrote:

```
while read line
do
    ./program_a line > $line.log 2>&1
done < parameter_file
```

The problem is that execution of program_a takes long time. Because each executions of program_a for each parameter is independent, So I think these executions can be run simultaneously. I don't know if it regards to multithreading or other technique. The following is my thought. Use & to run each executions on the background.

```
while read line
do
    ./program_a line $line.log 2>&1 &
done < parameter_file
```

Is there any better way of launching multiple tasks?

Comment: Your current way seems pretty good.

Comment: That's the standard way to do it. You can use the `wait` command to hold up proceedings until all the child processes are complete. There are programs like [`parallel`](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) that you could use too.

Comment: What do you mean by 'better' exactly (ie what properties might a 'better' way have)?  This is a normal and useful technique,  is it giving you issues?

Comment: Use [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Comment: I believe you want to `>> line.log` instead of `> line.log` (overwriting previously written infos) ? and  `$line` instead of `line`

Comment: With you method, you're lilely to run into issues where things will be "garbled-up" if 2 (or more) instance output data at the same time.

Comment: That's my typo. This should be $line instead of line.

Answer (score 5):

Did you know that `xargs` can launch tasks in parallel? [Check out `-P` `-n` parameters!](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html#xargs-options)

An example:

```
xargs -P 4 -n 1 ./program_a < parameter_file
```

That will start up to 4 (P=4) `program_a` instances for processing each line (n=1). You'll probably have to wrap `program_a` within a shell script or something so that child processes stdout & stderr can be redirected appropriately.

How this is better than putting processes to backgroud: Suppose you have 1000 lines in the input file, obviously you wouldn't want 1000 processes to be launched. Xargs allows you to look at it as a queue, with `P` workers each consuming and processing `n` items from it.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel you can get a logfile for each parameter and run one job per CPU core:

```
parallel --results logdir ./program_a :::: parameter_file
```

Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). You command line
with love you for it.